# visual studio 2010 performance analysis - where to specify key file

Tags: visual-studio, performance, strongname, assembly-signing

I am trying to do performance analysis with visual studio 2010. We are trying to use strong-named assemblies. I read in some articles that you have to re-sign the assemblies in the post-instrumentation event. In msdn is written you can specify only one key file.

My questions:

1. Where i can specify the key file
2. If it is not possible to specify a key-file directly so do i really have to specify the post-instrumentation event for every assembly i am trying to profile?